# How to send a song object from UIViewController to a TableViewController?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uikit, viewcontroller, avaudioplayer

I am building a basic music player app using AVAudioplayer. It's a tab bar. So far I have two taps, the first one is the home bar where I use a tableViewController to show a list of all the songs. In that TableviewController, I instantiated a regular UIViewController from the storyboard and I am using that as the detail screen, this screen has all the playback controls like the buttons, volume slider, and it plays the music as expected. I also have a "heart" button in that details screen, which shows up next to each song that's playing. The user can tap that button to favorite that song and it should automatically add to the favorites screen, kind of like when you add a song to your playlist in the apple music app. I used a programmatic segue from that button another tableView screen with its own class of FavoritesViewController. Here's the part I am stuck on. I want to send the current playing song from the detail screen to this favorites screen. I tried to find out the current song that's playing in the detail screen, and then send that very song to an array in FavoritesViewController and then use that array to populate the cell for that screen? Does that sound about right because I had no success? I also thought about protocol delegates.
I appreciate all the help.

Here are the three screens I am talking about from storyboard.
[image: Referenced screens from storyboard]